# Why would Task parallelism not speed up uploads / downloads?

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, task-parallel-library, azure-blob-storage

I wrote a simple C# Console application to measure the speed of downloading 20 Azure blob files (images each about 3mb) sequentially, and also in parallel.

I was under the impression that parallel downloading files would be significantly faster, but in my experience it actually takes a little bit longer.  Here is the code for the parallel downloads:

```
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string blobName in blobNames)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(blobName, FileMode.Create).Wait();
        });

        tasks.Add(t);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Am I approaching this wrong, causing an unnecessary bottleneck or something?  Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the benefits of parallelism?

Comment: Incomplete, you need to specify the resulting time and your available bandwidth. Without it it's just guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the impression that parallel downloading files would be significantly faster, but in my experience it actually takes a little bit longer. Here is the code for the parallel downloads:

Performance of IO operations depend on a lot of things.

You can only speed up by using parallelization if not all of the nodes are already performing at maximum.

For example, if one of the following conditions apply, you won't benefit and overall performance is likely to downgrade due to overhead:

Specifically for downloading:

- you are hitting your download/upload capacity of your network, LAN or internet, WAN
- you are hitting your maximum processing capacity (DISK, memory etc.)
- you are hitting the remote server's maximum upload capacity (note: can be IP bound, especially with cloud providers)

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, I was considering these but didn't think I was capping my bandwidth, for example.  I have little insight into the second bullet point but my task didn't seem too intensive compared to what I typically do.  So it's really #3 that had me wondering, that is, if the Azure servers were limiting me in some way, bound to my IP perhaps as you suggested.

Comment: If it is, it's somewhere in the subscription conditions. It can highly depend on which kind of subscription you have. Nevertheless, keep in mind that normally Azure is capable to provide you with more data than you can progress. So, typically I would check your own infra first; e.g.: perform a typical speed test to see if the arn't any bottlenecks, e to Wifi or something similar ;-)

Answer (score 7):

IMO, you shouldn't start a new task for downloading each blob, since this is an I/O intensive operation and not a computational intensive operation.
Using multiple tasks creates more overhead managing the Tasks while you actually do not gain anything.

Change your code to:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (string blobName in blobNames)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    tasks.Add(blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(blobName, FileMode.Create));
}


Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

This will spin up multiple async I/O requests, and your code will continue once all blobs have been downloaded from Azure blob-storage.
Since we're not awaiting on each download-task seperately, all downloads run concurrently.

Comment: Thank you, this was remarkably faster!  I want to clarify, though: I know I reduced the number of tasks by eliminating the "wrapper" task, but DownloadToFileAsync is still creating a task, so there will be 20 tasks running still, right?

Comment: `Task.Run` uses the threadpool most likely and has an upper bound on how many concurrent tasks/threads it will run.

Comment: Okay, interesting to know.  As an update, I noticed that the upload speeds using the same strategy didn't really improve much--maybe a tiny bit.  Downloads seemed much better, though.

Comment: @vargonian - if all your requests go to the same host - as it's Azure blob storage it's likely - you could also bump up against the [maximum concurrent requests per host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2) of just 2, which you can change, if you have the bandwidth to support more.  (This assumes `CloudBlockBlob` uses `ServicePoint` somewhere underneath, which is likely).

Comment: @vargonian : Yes, you're running a number of 'tasks' concurrently with this code.  You are however not wasting any threads, since you're not starting any (TPL) Tasks.  Instead, you're starting an I/O operation and you'll wait until the I/O operation finishes.  In the meantime, you can do other things.  This is a good read for more background info: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html